# Hiding curl Window on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows

[One of the answers on a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865988/fetching-a-url-without-c-extensions-libraries) mentioned that I can use curl to fetch a url; this can be done in `Thread.new` or in `Process.spawn`. But it seems that in either case, on Windows, I get a small command-prompt window appearing while curl is going out to the network.

I am invoking curl like this:

```
`curl "#{url}"`
```

Is there any way to hide the window so that it doesn't appear? Not only does it grab the focus away from the game (freezing it), but if I make frequent calls, it will be extremely annoying to the end user.

Comment: How are you calling the curl executable? is it thru a batch script?

Comment: Any particular reason why you need an external program to do HTTP requests? That's something a decent stdlib can do on its own quite well, usually.

Comment: Sorry, should have linked my old question. @Raam through backticks (`curl ...`)

Comment: @Joey yes, my environment can't use any Ruby libraries with C extensions. See my original question for more details.

Comment: Ah, unless you're directly using Windows' CreateProcess you're probably out of luck. I doubt Ruby exposes the flags for not creating a window in its API. Another option might be building curl with the GUI subsystem, so it won't create a console window (and won't create a window either, since there's no CreateWindow).

Comment: I recommend [`curb`](https://rubygems.org/gems/curb).

Comment: @Tass curb requires C extensions, which is not suitable for my solution. See linked question.

Comment: Oh. Use `require 'shellwords'` and `Array#shelljoin` in that case.

Comment: shellwords/shelljoin? What will that do?

Answer (score 3):

After some experimenting i got it working, no window when doubleclicking on the script, i use WMI from ruby, you just have to alter the path to curl. 
IMPORTANT: save it with the extension .rbw and make sure that rubyw.exe is associated with that extenstion.

```
#hidden_curl.rbw
require 'win32ole'

HIDDEN_WINDOW = 0
cmd = '"C:\\Program Files\\curl\\curl.exe" --output c:\\test2.txt "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869789/hiding-curl-window-on-windows"'
objStartup = WIN32OLE.connect("winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2:Win32_ProcessStartup")
objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_
objConfig.ShowWindow = HIDDEN_WINDOW
objProcess = WIN32OLE.connect("winmgmts:root\\cimv2:Win32_Process")
errReturn = objProcess.Create(cmd, nil, objConfig, nil)
```

Hope this works on your system.

Comment: I hope I already explained that I'm invoking ruby from within the interpreter, not clicking on any scripts. RBW won't make a difference, sadly. Thanks for effort though.

Comment: @ashes, i hope you at least try to run this, the .rbw is if you'd start it by doubleclicking, the magic is there, believe me

Comment: double-clicking doesn't make sense in the context of my game. I have end users who run a game engine which has content and Ruby code. I can't tell them "hey guys, run this RBW file, I promise it's awesome."

Comment: i see, sory that i didn't get that from the first time but my point is that in that case there is no need for .rwb, the console won't pop up if you run this code from within a normal ruby script, have you tried ?

Comment: Peter, that is pretty sweet! Is there any way to get access to stdout/stderr for the created process?

Comment: @Jamie, the idea here is to have no window but i suppose the errReturn variable holds what is output to the STDERR and STDOUT

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing the -s option to curl which will make it run in silent mode.
Something like

```
`curl -s "#{url}"`
```

I am guessing this will not show up the console.

Comment: Nope, still popped up the window.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is that you run the command in a subshell and the subshell in windows is CMD which is attached to a window.

I don't have a ruby to test the following but you could try :

```
IO#popen
Runs the specified command string as a subprocess; 
The subprocess‘s standard input and output will be connected to the returned IO object.
```

=> http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/IO.html if IO is available to you

you could also try to run 
`start /B curl -s "#{url}"`  instead of just curl see http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm for start specs.

Comment: Neither of these options seem to help; both display a command-prompt window briefly.

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't pop up a window on my W7 system

```
cmd = '"C:\Program Files\curl\curl.exe" --silent --output c:\test.txt "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869789/hiding-curl-window-on-windows"'
IO.popen(cmd)
```

or without creating a file

```
cmd = '"C:\Program Files\curl\curl.exe" --silent "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869789/hiding-curl-window-on-windows"'
IO.popen(cmd, "w+") { |io| puts io.readlines }
```

Comment: I'll take a look, but --silent is nothing new. I tried -s and it popped up a window.

Comment: i added the --silent just to be sure but it isn't necessary, i left it away and still don't get a console window, version two shows the output in the console window where i started the scripts, version one shows nothing at all

Comment: It shows a command-prompt window for me on XP. VX Ace has some weird system in place, it's not your everyday Ruby.

Comment: i guess you start this by doubleclicking a .rb script ? that is the only way i get a flashing window, but you can't avoid that for all i know, i have a vbs script that does exactly this with doubleclicking it you don't get a window and do get the result in the file, do i publish it ?

Comment: I have in-game events where I can pick an option like "script" and run any arbitrary script (within limits). There's a packed up subset of the Ruby language available; like I said in my other question, I can't use, say, net/http or open-uri.