# Ruby system call (on windows) without a popup command prompt

Tags: ruby, system, command-prompt

I am trying to tidy up a process that uses multiple system calls from inside a ruby script executed using rubyw.exe (1.8.7).

As far as I can understand the main reason for rubyw.exe is that it doesn't pop up a command prompt to distract the user. However it appears that the system calls from within that process still do generate these popups which is very distracting for the users of this process script.

Does anyone know how to do this?

There are lots of questions similar to this on SO but none which quite answers this, if I was using python this questions/answer would help (http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/46042/) but so far my searching hasn't found a way to accomplish this with ruby.

UPDATE: There is this thread here [Hiding curl Window on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869789/hiding-curl-window-on-windows) which is close but the only working solution there doesn't also allow you to get the standard output.

Comment: How do you make your system calls (`system`or backticks or `popen` or `%x{}`...? What do you call? What popups are coming? Is it only stdout, or are there real popups (Something like "Are you sure Y/N").

Comment: I have been using back ticks but have also tried system and %x, the popups are the command window (cmd.exe) which appears for a short period of time while the command executes.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Running_Multiple_Processes#Windows:_how_to_run_ruby_without_opening_up_a_command_window may be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going with the win32-open3 gem. Because fork isn't implemented on windows systems you can't use the built in open3 and you'll need to do a

```
gem install win32-open3
```

However this comes with flags that you can pass to the call method, in particular

> There are a couple of differences in the Windows version for open3
>   (which
>       also apply to Open4.popen4) - the mode flag and the show flag.  For the
>       mode, you can specify either 't' (text, the default) or 'b' (binary) as a
>       second argument. **For the show flag, you can specify either true or false,
>       which will show the console window, or not, depending on the value you
>       pass.  *The default is false*.**

Users of this particular script are no longer bombarded with 15 cmd windows that constantly steal focus, so .... win?